# Angular 2 project structure planning

Tags: javascript, angular, directory-structure

So, I already passed Anguar 2 [QUICKSTART](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) guide and [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35346342/which-type-of-folder-structure-should-be-used-with-angular-2) some topics, related to my question. Currently I'm trying to implement latest (2.1) Angular version.
So, I have next files in my angular app root directory

```
app.component.ts
main.ts
app.module.ts
```

If you are fimilar with Angular 2.1, then you may know that `directives` key word was removed from component decorator, so I should register any new directive in `app.module.ts` file, like so

```
@NgModule({
    imports:    [ BrowserModule ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        AutoGrowDirective,
        DirecComponent,
        BaseComponent
    ],
    bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
```

So, to add a new page to my project I can simply specify new route and assign it to a some base component, let's call them `page component`.

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
            {
                path: '',
                component: BaseComponent
            },
            {
                path: 'heroes',
                component: DirecComponent
            }
        ])
```

But, what if I want a lot of different components, that will be included to my `page components`?

I need to create a lot of reusable micro components, is it ok to add them into `declarations` array, possible I need a 200 of them or something.
When my project bootstraping - all of them will be loaded? Even if not all of them included to currently requested `page component`?

I want to hear your thoughts about it, thanks!