# Dividing pages to components properly in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, angular-components

I have the following folder structure in my project:

[image]

I have a `list-page` and there are some operations e.g. `create`, `update` and `delete` performed via a modal dialog. In this scene, I think I should create 4 pages for each of these operations (CRUD) and some components for them. But at this stage I am really confused as I have always used components for each page. How to divide the pages properly and name each page and components in it? I thought something like that:

```
|-- home
     |-- components
         |-- list | .html & .ts
         |-- create-form | .html & .ts
         |-- update-form | .html & .ts
         |-- delete | .html & .ts

     |-- pages
         |-- list | .html & .ts
```

I think there is no need to create a separate pages for each component, because there are 3 buttons like Add, Update and Delete on the List grid and I can render corresponding component to a modal dialog located on the list page. Am I wrong? Or how should I organize these pages and components? It would be also nice to give examples by names.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are going in right way and here are my thoughts

> *I think there is no need to create a separate pages for each component..*

Yeah, no need to create separate component for each operation.

> *how should I organize these pages and components?*

Create components like below structure (I mean single component for all the actions) :

```
|-- home
     |-- components
         |-- form-operations | .html & .ts & .scss

     |-- pages
         |-- list | .html & .ts
```

Here we can use the form-operations (name could be better one) components for multiple use cases like Create, Update and Delete by using **[`@Input`](https://angular.io/api/core/Input)**.

Design the Component something like the way in this [***`stackBlitz`***](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-o8rtqi?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)

**Edit :**

Please try to follow this material [*`stackBlitz`*](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-dialog-example) for more info about calling matDialog.

We can use the `editMode` to differentiate between the actions in the dialog component (in this case Hello Component).

```
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(HelloComponent,{
  data: {
     editMode: this.editMode
  }
 });

 dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((confirmed: boolean) => {
  console.log("closed the dialog");
 });
```

**P.S:** you can remove this in app.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="editMode">
    <form-operations [editMode]="editMode"></form-operations>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable explanations. May it be a good idea to create separate components for each operation and render them to a modal dialog that is called by buttons on the list? Could you pls give an example regarding to this scenario? On the other hand, if I want to use reusable components like forms, what changes should I make? Or what should I keep consideration? Regards.

Comment: @Jack updated the answer, plz check

Comment: Sorry for late reply, but I have just found to check. First of all thanks a lot for your useful helps and voted up. Then, is there a detailed example covering all CRUD operations using reusable components? It is also ok if you suggest a proper approach or example that you approved.